# Typewriter animation using Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm having an issue and I don't find the answer by myself.
I'm trying to make the following code work. Actually it doesn't work in my Vue project.

```js
const text = document.getElementById("text");

const phrases = [
  "I'm John Doe",
  "I'm student",
  "I'm developer",
];

let currentPhraseIndex = 0;
let currentCharacterIndex = 0;
let currentPhrase = "";
let isDeleting = false;

function loop() {
  const currentPhraseText = phrases[currentPhraseIndex];

  if (!isDeleting) {
    currentPhrase += currentPhraseText[currentCharacterIndex];
    currentCharacterIndex++;
  } else {
    currentPhrase = currentPhrase.slice(0, -1);
    currentCharacterIndex--;
  }

  text.innerHTML = currentPhrase;

  if (currentCharacterIndex === currentPhraseText.length) {
    isDeleting = true;
  }

  if (currentCharacterIndex === 0) {
    currentPhrase = "";
    isDeleting = false;
    currentPhraseIndex++;
    if (currentPhraseIndex === phrases.length) {
      currentPhraseIndex = 0;
    }
  }

  const spedUp = Math.random() * (80 - 50) + 50;
  const normalSpeed = Math.random() * (300 - 200) + 200;
  const time = isDeleting ? spedUp : normalSpeed;
  setTimeout(loop, time);
}

loop();
```

```html
<h2 id="text"></h2>
```

As you can see the code is actually working. Checkout the errors I have in my from my Vue Js project.

[image]

Do not hesitate, if you have any suggestions to improve my code according to Vue of course.

Comment: Could you add your vue code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to make it work.
The following code is updated and works using Vue.js 3.

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const phrases = [
  "I am John Doe.",
  "I am student.",
  "I am developer.",
];

const currentPhraseIndex = ref(0);
const currentCharacterIndex = ref(0);
const currentPhrase = ref("");
const isDeleting = ref(false);

function loop() {
  const currentPhraseText = phrases[currentPhraseIndex.value];

  if (!isDeleting.value) {
    currentPhrase.value += currentPhraseText[currentCharacterIndex.value];
    currentCharacterIndex.value++;
  } else {
    currentPhrase.value = currentPhrase.value.slice(0, -1);
    currentCharacterIndex.value--;
  }

  if (currentCharacterIndex.value === currentPhraseText.length) {
    isDeleting.value = true;
  }

  if (currentCharacterIndex.value === 0) {
    currentPhrase.value = "";
    isDeleting.value = false;
    currentPhraseIndex.value++;
    if (currentPhraseIndex.value === phrases.length) {
      currentPhraseIndex.value = 0;
    }
  }

  const spedUp = Math.random() * (80 - 50) + 50;
  const normalSpeed = Math.random() * (300 - 200) + 200;
  const time = isDeleting.value ? spedUp : normalSpeed;
  setTimeout(loop, time);
}

loop();
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
      <h1 id="title">{{ currentPhrase }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put variables in data property and function in methods, or i composition api make variables reactive:

```js
const { ref, reactive, onMounted } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const opt = reactive({
      currentPhraseIndex: 0, 
      currentCharacterIndex: 0, 
      currentPhrase: "", 
      isDeleting: false
    })
    const phrases = reactive([
      "I'm John Doe",
      "I'm student",
      "I'm developer"
    ])
    const text = ref('')
    const loop = () => {
      const currentPhraseText = phrases[opt.currentPhraseIndex];
      if (!opt.isDeleting) {
        opt.currentPhrase += currentPhraseText[opt.currentCharacterIndex];
        opt.currentCharacterIndex++;
      } else {
        opt.currentPhrase = opt.currentPhrase.slice(0, -1);
        opt.currentCharacterIndex--;
      }
      text.value = opt.currentPhrase;
      if (opt.currentCharacterIndex === currentPhraseText.length) {
        opt.isDeleting = true;
      }
      if (opt.currentCharacterIndex === 0) {
        opt.currentPhrase = "";
        opt.isDeleting = false;
        opt.currentPhraseIndex++;
        if (opt.currentPhraseIndex === opt.phrases?.length) {
          opt.currentPhraseIndex = 0;
        }
      }
      const spedUp = Math.random() * (80 - 50) + 50;
      const normalSpeed = Math.random() * (300 - 200) + 200;
      const time = opt.isDeleting ? spedUp : normalSpeed;
      setTimeout(loop, time);
    }
    onMounted(() => {
      loop()
    })
    return {
      text
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <h2>{{ text }}</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code and still have Vue errors and the loop was not working anymore. Anyway, it helps me to understand how I could update it. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line

```
if (opt.currentCharacterIndex === currentPhraseText.length) {
  opt.isDeleting = true;
  opt.currentPhraseIndex = 0; //  <===== you have to add this line 
}
```